# Maintain multiple states in ember

Tags: javascript, url-routing, ember.js

Consider an ftp browser application written using Ember. It is likely to have a perhaps a tree view for the hierarchy and a list view for the files of the current selection. And store the current selection in the URL as:

baseUrl/#path

e.g.

www.emberftp.com/#stuff/docs/programming

Not that difficult.

However! Now consider extending this application to having two browser views sort of like Windows Commander. And that one view is currently browsing /stuff/docs/programming and the other /backup/images.

Obviously this would require multiple outlets at some level but what happens to the URL?

First of all, is this at all supported? If it is, how should this be set up with routes and serialization/deserialzaion? And what would the URL actually look like?

baseUrl/#?browser1=/stuff/docs/programming&browser2=/backup/images

Maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The Ember router will update the browser's URL to be a reflection of the current application state. This is done so a user can return to or share his current state by a URL. It is important to note that the router can only ever be in one state at a given time.

The router is all about using serialization and deserialization to recreate it's state. This is basically the idea of turning the current application state into a sharable URL and vice-versa. To solve the question you posted you should probably have a model, lets call it `window`, that has many `browsers`. Then when you are loading your window via a URL you can easily reconstruct all of your ftp browsers. I think that dealing with one model makes the serialization/deserialization process a lot easier to conceptualize.

Anyway, here is how your models might look.

```
App.Window.create({
  id: 1,
  browsers: [1, 2]
});

App.Browser.create({
  id: 1,
  path: "/stuff/docs/programming"
});

App.Browser.create({
  id: 2,
  path: "/backup/images"
})
```

And your router would only have to know how to deserialize "/windows/:window_id".

Comment: The paths are arbitrary paths to any location on any ftp server. It would be impossible to have a predefined states for that. In some way both paths must be serialized to the URL in a way that it is obvious when deserializing which path belongs to which browser.

The problem is that it is obvious how to arrange an URL when it only should affect a single path in in a tree of states, but what if it needs to affect several?

What one would need is is way of describing hierarcial data on the URL in a way that makes sense to Ember. I guess one could always base64 encode a json structure, but...

Comment: Right. So find a way to serialize the ``window`` object such that it can be recreated by entering a URL. This could be base64 or url encoding a list of paths. The whole idea is a URL can be used to recreate/create an object and state.